# How to get doctors lists from google places api

Tags: iphone

sir

Now, I want to develop app that find hospitals and doctors around me by using Google Places Api.

Google Places Api is perfect to find hospitals.
But for doctors, i want only to get humans's information.

Right now, when I try to search doctors by using google places api , I always get health service center or hospital;s information with human doctor's.

Following is url that I used for it.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=300&types=doctor&name=&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBKFKov5f5YoSDRnWrT3y7MFf9DfsdRgCg

So, any idea to filter them so i can only get human doctor's information? (not establishment information).

If anyone knows about it then, would you please help me?

Best regards.

Comment: very late answer, but you should remove your API key :-)